# php register_shutdown_function usage

Tags: php

I'm trying to handle fatal errors using `register_shutdown_function`. I want to show an error page when this function is invoked, something like this:

`

```
register_shutdown_function('en795HandleShutdown');
...
function en795HandleShutdown() {
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
echo '<head>';
echo '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>';
echo '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/>';
echo '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"/>';
echo '  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />';
echo '  <title>SOMETITLE</title>';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body >';
echo '<div><div>';
echo '      <h1>Error</h1>';
echo '      <h2>Dead End.<h2>';
echo '  </div></div>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
}
```

`

I generate an error by setting `ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);` and executing without the database to get the `Fatal error:  Maximum execution time...`. But nothing happen when function is invoked. I guess what's going wrong. Forgot to mention: `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to handle fatal errors. You are better off using:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

The link, is to `set_error_handler();`

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
echo '<head>';
echo '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>';
echo '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/>';
echo '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"/>';
echo '  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />';
echo '  <title>SOMETITLE</title>';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body >';
echo '<div><div>';
echo '      <h1>Error</h1>';
echo '      <h2>Dead End.<h2>';
echo '  </div></div>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>'; 


}


 set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

`register_shutdown_function();` executes at the  very end, when your script has finishing processing, so once your entire script has finished. You will be presented with your 'handler'

Answer (score 0):

The answer contributed is wrong for the question. set_error_handler callbacks do not work for fatal errors. For that you must use register_shutdown_function. One way to tell if it is being called when a fatal error occurs is to call error_get_last (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) and, if it returns an array, check the type if it is E_ERROR.